# Could there be more than one correct answer for the indefinite integral $\int\tan x\,dx$?

Tags: calculus

I solved this integral by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sec x$ in order to get: $$\int\frac {\tan x\sec x}{\sec x} \,dx$$
This would be in the form $\int \frac {du}{u} $ , out of which I should be able to get:$$\ln \left | \sec x\right |+ C$$ However, the answer my text later provides is: $$ -\ln \left |\cos x \right | +C$$ 
Can both of these be correct? If so, how are these answers equal to one another?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $\sec = 1/\cos$.

Answer (score 6):

They are indeed the same. As the comment section provides, $\sec(x)=\dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}$

What this means is that
$$\ln|\sec(x)|=\ln|\dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}|=\ln|1|-\ln|\cos(x)|=0-\ln|\cos(x)|=-\ln|\cos(x)|$$

I used the rule that $\ln(\dfrac{a}{b})=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$

---

Also generally speaking, an **indefinite integral** is a family of functions. Notice that you can also add constants to your indefinite integral and it is still the same. For example the answer could have also been $1-\ln|\cos(x)|$, since the constant goes away when you take the derivative of it.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same as shown by @KSplitX and the comment, but I think it's worth knowing how your text is likely to have proceeded to get their answer. Using the standard log integral 
$$
\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \, dx = \log |f(x)|+C
$$
Your integral is
$$
\int \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \, dx = -\int \frac{-\sin x}{\cos x} \, dx
=-\log|\cos x|+C
$$